# GeoDjango ORM lookup wrongly transforms geometry to unwanted SRID in SQL

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

In the query below lookup with `geometry` variable wrongly transforms `geometry` to unwanted SRID in SQL.

```
Buildings.objects.annotate(
    area_krovak=Transform('area', self.KROVAK_SRID), 
    intersection_area=RawSQL('ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(area, {krovak}), ST_GeomFromEWKB(\'\\x{district_geom}\')))'.format(district_geom=geometry.ewkb.hex(), krovak=5514), [])
).filter(area_krovak__intersects=geometry)
```

`Building.area`  is in db a `MultipolygonField()`, in db there is by default SRID 4326 (WGS84). `geometry` is `GEOSGeometry` in Krovak projection (SRID 5514). To make ST_Intersection work I need both in the same projection, so I added the field `area_krovak` in the corresponding projection. But the `=geometry` part in lookup `area_krovak__intersects=geometry` results in the following SQL (when I print `.query`)

```
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromEWKB('blabla'::bytea), 4326)
```

For some reason Django transforms it to 4326 and therefore it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Buildings.objects.annotate(
    area_krovak=Transform('area', self.KROVAK_SRID, output_field=MultiPolygonField(srid=5514)), 
    intersection_area=RawSQL('ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(area, {krovak}), ST_GeomFromEWKB(\'\\x{district_geom}\')))'.format(district_geom=geometry.ewkb.hex(), krovak=5514), [])
).filter(area_krovak__intersects=geometry)
```

Adding `output_field` with appropriate SRID just solved it